# Estimating parameters of inifinite scale mixture from data

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, mixture-distribution, gamma-distribution

Suppose that I have an infinite scale mixture of zero-mean normal distributions, whose mixing distribution is gamma with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The data is thus distributed according to a generalized Student's $t$ distribution. I am handed a pair of samples, $(z,y)$, generated through the following procedure, and asked to estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$. First, $x$ is sampled directly from the Gamma distribution. Then it is corrupted by gaussian noise, so that $z = x+N(0,\delta)$. Finally, $y \sim N(0,1/x).$

Are there known estimators for $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: If you're handed $(x,y)$, what information about $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is there in $y$ that's not already in $x$? As such, why wouldn't you just use the usual MLE for the parameters on the $x$-sample? If you only had $y$, that would be a less trivial question. However, you can estimate the variance and the degrees of freedom from the resulting $t$-distribution of $y$, and hence obtain estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @Glen_b, you're right. I misstated the problem. The sample $y$ from the Gamma is corrupted by gaussian noise, so that $y \sim \textrm{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)+N(0,\delta)$

Comment: Do you mean that $x$ is corrupted? In your original, $y$ is normal, not gamma. It makes even less sense now than before. Could you please edit your question to clearly reflect the actual circumstances? Do you need a third variable?

Comment: @Glen_b, right again. I meant that $x$ is corrupted. Edited to reflect this change.

Comment: Well, there are definitely ways to estimate the parameters; three examples: (i) you could use ML; (ii) you could take a Bayesian approach; or (iii) you could use Method of Moments (MoM), just for starters. Consider MoM for a second: $\text{E}(Z)\text{Var}(Y)$ should be just a function of $\alpha$, so the MoM estimate of $\alpha$ would be obtained from setting that function of $\hat\alpha$ equal to $\bar z s^2_y$ and solving for $\hat\alpha$. An estimate of $\beta$ can then be backed out from $E(Z)$ or $\text{Var}(Y)$. Finally, an estimate of $\delta$ can then be backed out of $\text{Var}(Z)$.

Comment: (ctd) .... -- assuming I didn't make any errors. That's not to suggest that MoM is a particularly desirable way to estimate the parameters in this case, just that it's quite straightforward. If ML is not too hard, that's probably what I'd do. If there's any prior information on the parameters, then a Bayesian approach is the obvious way to proceed.